# How do I get to the content of an attribute in an input tag?

Tags: xpath

tell me pliz
hiding here xpath trying to take the contents of data-sell from the input

> input [@ data-currency = 'USD'] / @ data-buy

with such a request gives

> data-buy = "74.19" data-buy = "74.19" data-buy = "74.19"

but I need, first of all, the correct input and I do not need only the content of the data attribute without the attribute itself, that is:

> 74.19

not completely

> data-buy = "74.19"

on the page this code

```
<input type = "hidden" data-currency = "USD" data-sell = "78" data-buy = "74.19">
<input type = "hidden" data-currency = "USD" data-sell = "78" data-buy = "74.19">
<input type = "hidden" data-currency = "USD" data-sell = "78" data-buy = "74.19">
```

Comment: `/@data-buy` should return value only. Probably your issue caused by tool specific behavior. Which one do you use?

Comment: I'am use plguin for google chrome - chropath